# Magento2 contact form in CMS page

Tags: magento2, cms-block, contact-form, cms-pages

in magento 1.x for add contact form in CMS page i use next code

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="{{store direct_url='contacts'}}/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

How I can add contact form in CMS page in magento 2

Answer (score 23):

**Call your contact form block with template file in the cms pages.**

**Try below code :**

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Any ideas how to stop it from redirecting back to contact/index/index on form submission. Would be nice to just submit the form, and remain on the page with the contact block in it?

Comment: @GrahamWharton - Then you need do some workaround with Ajax based form submission.

Comment: @GrahamWharton I'm sorry for bumping up this old answer. But maybe you cold put a redirect on "contact/index/index" to the page that your contact form is on. Of course this would only be an option if you want your page to replace the default contact page.

Answer (score 5):

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```