# How to change contact page url in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, contact-form

When we entering contact form in footer from any page it redirect only - /contact/index/ 
Any options such that we can submit form in footer any page without redirect to another page

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196432/magento-2-send-form-data-to-controller-using-ajax-and-return-result-to-phtml) link to submit form using ajax

Comment: Any option without using Ajax contact form submit in footer without url redirect

Comment: No, There are two option either redirect the user to that URL or submit the form using AJAX

Comment: But, how to add Ajax in form - I added contact form in footer section using this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156040/magento2-contact-form-in-cms-page

Comment: Ok, you need to override Magento_Contact::form.phtml into your custom theme OR define into custom module check [here](https://webkul.com/blog/override-phtml-file-magento2/) for how to override phtml file and need to define ajax code there like as I mentioned how to define ajax code [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196432/magento-2-send-form-data-to-controller-using-ajax-and-return-result-to-phtml)

Comment: After adding ajax contact form not working

Comment: @Gagan, please confirm whether you want to submit form using Ajax or just want to redirect back to the same page from where the contact form was submitted?

Comment: Contact form was not submitted, I need no action perform after submit form. please help. It show only current page after form submission