# How to remove url /contact/index in contact page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, contact-us

When we entering contact form in footer from any page it redirect only - /contact/index/ Any options such that we can submit form in footer section not redirect /contact/index

[image]

After submit form it show -
[image]

I add contact form in footer section using this link - [Magento2 contact form in CMS page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156040/magento2-contact-form-in-cms-page), how to submit form without redirection and contact details not show in above footer section .Please reply me

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you want to redirect back to the page, where the customer was before sending the contact request.

To do so, you need to create a simple module. Please follow the steps below to accomplish this.

**Step 1:** Create the **registration.php** file **app/code/Stack/ContactRedirect** folder and paste the following content in it:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Stack_ContactRedirect',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:** Create the **module.xml** file under **app/code/Stack/ContactRedirect/etc** folder with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Stack_ContactRedirect" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

**Step 3:** Define 2 plugins under **app/code/Stack/ContactRedirect/etc/frontend/di.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post">
        <plugin name="contactus_before_submit" type="Stack\ContactRedirect\Plugin\BeforePost"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post">
        <plugin name="contactus_submit" type="Stack\ContactRedirect\Plugin\AfterPost"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 4:** Create before plugin class under **app/code/Stack/ContactRedirect/Plugin/BeforePost.php** with the following content:

```
<?php
namespace Stack\ContactRedirect\Plugin;

class BeforePost {
    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_coreSession;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect, \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
    ) {
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    }

    public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject) {
        $this->_coreSession->start();
        $this->_coreSession->setRerererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return;
    }
}
```

**Step 5:** Create after plugin class under **app/code/Stack/ContactRedirect/Plugin/AfterPost.php** with the following content:

```
<?php
namespace Stack\ContactRedirect\Plugin;

class AfterPost {
    protected $_coreSession;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
    ) {
        $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    }

    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject, $result) {
        $this->_coreSession->start();
        return $result->setPath($this->_coreSession->getRerererUrl());
    }
}
```

**Step 6:** Your module is complete now. Run **`setup upgrade`** and then **`flush Magento's cache`** to see this module in action.

**Note:** There was a need to create before plugin also because in after plugin, there is no way to get the referral URL.

Comment: This still works well. Slight mistake in step 5 under the namespace, should be Stack\ContactRedirect\Plugin

Comment: @MaddocksL, great catch. changed now.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. You can create a after plugin of controller like below.

**di.xml** under etc folder

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post">
        <plugin name="contactus_submit" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Post"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Post
{
    /**
     * After plugin for execute method of \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post
     *
     * @param \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject, $result
     * @return Redirect
     */
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject, $result)
    {
        return $result->setPath('custom-url');
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: How to create plugin for contact form - please explain full steps of controller

Comment: @gaganbafna I have already write down the all steps. please try this and let me know if you face any issue while doing this.

Comment: did it work for you? let me know if any help needed

Comment: I used custom theme in magento , the path of di.xml file is app\etc and what is path of post.php

Comment: You need to create a custom module for this. You can check this url to create your custom module https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/

Comment: after creating the module please follow the steps which I given in answer. let me know if you have any issue while doing this.