# Contact form in CMS page with form.additional.info

Tags: layout, magento2.3.1, cms-pages, contact-form, containers

I'm trying to add the contact form to my CMS page.
I can add

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

as indicated on [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156040/magento2-contact-form-in-cms-page) but it doesn't load the `form.additional.info` part of the contact form.

I need that for the Re-Captcha form to show. The `form.phtml` does include a call to the additional info block `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>` but it doesn't render.

Magento's default layout for the contact us page looks like this

```
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

But I can't figure out how to get the `<container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>` into the CMS page through the layout updates XMl field.

Comment: Do you want to add any content to contact cms page rather than contact form? If yes then where to do you want to show the contact form after/before the cms content?

Comment: The contact form is in the middle of my content

Comment: did you added the receptcha code on your contact form.phtml? If yes, your code will work as it is.

Comment: I'm not using *my* form - I'm using Magento's and in 2.3.1 it's included

Comment: Could you solve it?